# Fixed Div moves to left and right when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have this fixed div:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

It moves from right to left when resizing the window. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because when using values in `%` the measurements are done relative to the `width/height` of container(can also be body) . So if you resizes browser window the sizes changes so measurements also changes .

Here measurements changes according to body.

To prevent this you can use absolute values like in `px` `cm` ..... in `bottom` `top` property